Как сделать так что бы игра спрашивал игрока после нажатия кнопки играть какого персонажа выбрать?
Это код выбора персонажа:
extends Control

# Глобальный сигнал для передачи выбранного персонажа

signal character_selected(character_name: String)

# Объявляем переменную для имени персонажа

var character_name String
func_ready():
    # Подключаем кнопки к функциям выбора персонажа
    character1_button.connect("pressed", self, "_on_character1_selected")


func_on_character1_selected():
    character_name = "player2" # Имя первого персонажа
    emit_signal("character_selection", character_name)


func_on_play_button_pressed():
    get_tree().change_scene("res://play/my_world.tscn")'

Глобальный сигнал :
extends Node

var character_name: String = ""
# Сигнал для уведомления о выборе персонажа

signal character_selected(character_name: String)

Код меню игры:
extends Canvas Layer

# Ссылка на кнопку "Играть"

@onready var play_button = $PlayButton

func_ready():
    play_button.connect("pressed", self, "_on_play_button_pressed")

func_on_play_button_pressed():
    # Переход к сцене выбора персонажস
    get_tree().change_scene("res://CharacterSelection.tscn")

func_on_start_game_pressed() -> void
    get_tree().change_scene_to_file("res://CharacterSelction/character_selection.tscn

Это уровня:
signal character_selected(character_name: String)


func_on_character_selected(character_name: String):
    var character = preload("res://CharacterSelction/"+ character_name + ".tscn").instantiate()
    add_child(characte)

func_ready():
    # Подключаем сигнал от сцены выбора персонажа
    var character_selection_scene = preload("res://CharacterSelction/character_selection.tscn").instance()

    character_selection_scene.connect("character_selected", self, "_on_character_selected")

    add_child(character_selection_scene)

Здравствуйте я делаю 2D пиксельную игру в Godot 4.3 и я совсем новичок и особо не знаю коды Godot у меня возникла проблема Я не знаю как сделать так что бы после нажатия кнопки игра спрашивала какого персонажа выбрать я указал путь к сцене у кнопки и создал глобальный сигнал и нечего не работает пожалуйста кто может скажите как заранее благодарю
Поправка: Я использовал глобальный сигнал что бы все переменные могли видеть какого персонажа выбрал игрок.Выбор я установил через кнопки Button и через него сигналы уже в сцену с уровнем сейчас я удалил код когда выявились ошибки я испугался что все придется делать сначала.У меня уже такое было что из за ошибки мне пришлось удалить весь проект и начинать все сначала.

Приведите ваш код, и подробно опишите проблему, тогда мы вам поможем.

Извините я удалил код Я могу его ещё раз написать и отправить или вам нужен код сцены игры и персонажа ?
